# Atomically delete a list of paths

Tags: bash, unix

I need to be able to delete an arbitrary list of paths (both files and directories) and, if any of the deletions fail, I need to be able to roll back.  Is there a Unix command that can accommodate this?  If not, a bash script works as well.

Answer (score 3):

There's unlikely to be a command that does this in its full generality.  The O/S does not support atomically deleting multiple paths, so it is hard to impossible for a command to do so.  Consider a SIGKILL; the command cannot recover, and the kernel won't know it has to undo what was done, so the atomicity is broken.

You can approximate atomicity by moving the deleted files or directories to a trash folder, and then only deleting the contents of the trash folder when everything else has succeeded (and recover the data from the trash folder if anything goes wrong).  But it isn't guaranteed atomic.  And you have to worry about where to place the trash when the files are on different file systems, so you need a per-file-system trash folder.  You also need to worry about atomically deleting 30 files all called 'makefile'; that means you're going to need directory hierarchy information in the trash directory (probably actual directories under the trash directory since anything else is, ultimately, ambiguous).